# How to pass parameters to web api2

Tags: c#, rest, routes, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

Controller signature:

```
public class UserAlertsController : ApiController

public IHttpActionResult Post(Guid id, List<long> users)
```

Route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Postman request:

```
http://localhost:50828/api/UserAlerts/4af3fee7-84ae-48fa-9215-45a00c35dbf

Content-Type application/json

[1,2]
```

With the above setup I receieve the message:

```
"Message": "The request is invalid.",
"MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry
                  for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid'"
```

I also use the standard global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Can any one tell me where I'm going wrong

If I change my action signature to:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(string id, long[] users)
```

Then it is bound correctly, but the error is thrown if id is changed to a Guid.

Comment: You are passing guid as a route parameter but your route didn't match the url you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You made a mistake to pass `4af3fee7-84ae-48fa-9215-45a00c35dbf` that is not a GUID and you should pass `4af3fee7-84ae-48fa-9215-45a00c35dbf6` Pay attention to **6** at the end.

**Based on your original Question**

The problem is with your route, you should use: `"api/{controller}/{id}"` as route url template.

You are passing guid as a route parameter but your route didn't match the url you are using.

Open `WebApi.Config` and change your default route to this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also make sure you have registered your `WebApiConfig` in `global.asax` in `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

**Side Note:**

By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:

- If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string.
- For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Answer (score 0):

The GUID value you're passing is in the header. You can specify you want to receive the value from the uri via the `FromUri` attribute:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]Guid id, List<long> users)
```

Another problem is that you have "api" part in your HTTP URL:

```
http://localhost:50828/api/UserAlerts/4af3fee7-84ae-48fa-9215-45a00c35dbf
```

While your controller is missing it in the declaration. Either remove the "api" part from your url, or add it to your route.

Either this:

```
http://localhost:50828/UserAlerts/4af3fee7-84ae-48fa-9215-45a00c35dbf
```

Or modify your `url` under `MapRoute`:

```
url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Comment: Thanks. Cant I send the guid in the querystring and the list in the body?

Comment: The op is passing guid as a route parameter but his route didn't match the url he is using.

Comment: @DavidB I missed the fact that you're sending the guid inside the URI. Edited my answer.

Comment: I I remove api, or change the route I get a 404. Ive added the FromURI attribute, but get the same issue

Comment: Just realised I had another route setup overwriting the first. Have edited the post. It did contain 'api' :) Sorry about that

Comment: @DavidB Try removing the `MapRoute` config you just removed from your code. The one containing `controller = "Home"`, etc. Also, where is the `{action}` attribute? It seems to be missing from your declaration.

Comment: My action names are http verbs so are not required as far as I believe. thanks for the help I have a meeting now so will pick up later